# VBA | How to create a class module which builds objects and assigns them to an array/collection

Tags: vba, excel, class, object

I am somewhat new to coding and may not use the correct terminology, hopefully, what I say makes sense.

I have created a class module to build objects. My class module currently has some variables (I intend to add some methods as I build upon my code).

```
'CLASS MODULE NAMED clsNodes

Public i As Single
Public j As Single
Public coll As Collection
```

My module will build objects based on cell value input by the user

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Single, j As Single
Dim ni_nodes As Single, nj_anchors As Single

ni_nodes = range("A1")
nj_nodes = range("A2")

For i = 1 to ni_nodes
    For j = 1 to nj_nodes

        Set node = New clsNodes
        node.i = i
        node.j = j

    Next j
Next i
```

The current problem with my code is that when it steps through my for loop the object node is overwritten every step it runs through the j for loop.

What I want to do is create a new object or add the object to a collection so I can easily reference the object and its variables. For example in my module I would like to call up my nodes similar to...

```
1stnode_i_value = node(1).i
3rdnode_j_value = node(3).j
```

Hopefully, this makes sense... I may not be using the best approach so please enlightened me.

Answer (score 1):

A collection can only be keyed with a `String` value. You can store an object instance as an *item* in a collection, but collections come with many shortcomings so go for better options, like an array or a dictionary.

Since we want to keep this simple, I would go with an array. Your instance of the class is overwritten because you are not saving it. To save all of your class instances you can do this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Single, j As Single
Dim ni_nodes As Single, nj_anchors As Single
dim arr() as variant
dim cnt as integer


ni_nodes = range("A1")
nj_nodes = range("A2")

redim arr(1 to ni_nodes*nj_nodes)
cnt=0
For i = 1 to ni_nodes
    For j = 1 to nj_nodes

        Set node = New clsNodes
        node.i = i
        node.j = j
        cnt=cnt+1
        set arr(cnt)=node
    Next j
Next i
```

to retrieve your objects from the array you should do this:

```
dim obj as object
set obj=arr(i) 'i is the index you want
```

or:

```
dim obj as clsNode
set obj=new clsNode
set obj=arr(i)
```

Comment: Although some prefer dictionaries, I've never had a problem storing a class instance in a collection.  What exactly do you mean by a "user defined object"?

Comment: I mean you cannot have keys in collections to be user-defined class instances. Tim used collections in his answer, but all instances will be stored as items. The most valuable aspect of collections and dictionaries is their keys uniqueness and it is not used in this example. Plus, we don't know what exactly will happen to the instances after storing in the collection/array. If the user wants to manipulate the stored data, then a collection will fail him.

Comment: Collections are read-only.You can add or remove an item but you cannot change the value of the item. If you are going to be changing the values in a group of items then you will need to use an array.

Comment: You write: *Collections are read-only*, but that is not the case. There is no issue with changing the value of an item, whether or not there is a key.  It is the case that the key in a collection must be string data type.  And there are advantages to dictionaries, but that has nothing to do with your initial statement *You cannot store a user-defined object in a collection*.  If you post this as a new question, I would be happy to provide examples demonstrating both how to store a user-defined object in a collection; and also how to change the value of such an item when stored in a collection.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you need to read my comment attentively, I cleared out that I meant collections' key choice is limited and a user-defined class instance cannot be a key. And you cannot change the value of an item in collection directly, you have to remove it and add it again, so that is not called changing directly.

Comment: You are incorrect regarding how to change the value of an item in a collection.  I did agree that the key choice is limited to a string.

Comment: How about you just show us how you change it without removing and adding it?

Comment: See [How can I change the value of Class properties when stored in a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533028/how-can-i-change-the-value-class-properties-when-stored-in-a-collection). This relates to the original posters question and shows how to both store the UDO and alter it in the collection object without removing and adding it back.

Comment: I had upvoted this answer out of misreading the context of the question / it is correct to say that you cannot add a UDT to a `Collection`. However OP involves no UDT, and a class module is not a UDT. Upvote retracted.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Mat I think you are confusing things here. The gist of the statement is that collections have shortcomings in terms of acceptable data types for keys and regardless of whether a user defined class instance is considered a UDT or not, it cannot be stored as a key.

Comment: @Mat'sMug BTW  I have not used UDT, I said User defined object, which is an instance of a user defined class.

Comment: @Ibo I totally misread that. I've edited your answer to clarify the wording - I've also reinstated my upvote, except I would love to read about the shortcomings of `VBA.Collection`, especially when objects are involved.

Comment: @ibo  I like your answer much better now that you have edited the beginning of your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your objects in a Collection:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Node As clsNodes, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim coll As New Collection, n

    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 5

            Set Node = New clsNodes
            Node.i = i
            Node.j = j
            coll.Add Node

        Next j
    Next i

    'list out stored objects
    For Each n In coll
        Debug.Print n.i, n.j
    Next n

End Sub
```