# How can I change the value of Class properties when stored in a Collection

Tags: vba, excel

I want to store a class in a Collection and be able to alter the properties of the class without having to remove the collection item and add it back again.

My research has shown that the Item itself cannot be changed without the remove/replace operation, but what about the properties of the item.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this Q&A. You're asking about default behavior stuff. A collection stores a *pointer* to the object, it wouldn't know how to clone it anyway. Play with the undocumented `ObjPtr` function, you'll see.

Comment: @Mat'sMug It has to do with a conversation in comments with user: Ibo in regard to another question, in which he claimed in his answer (and with 1 upvote!) that one could not store a User Defined Object in a Collection, but was required to use a Dictionary.  When I pointed out this was not the case, and could not apparently convince him in the comment format, he requested I post an example.

Comment: Ok found it. Funny thing, that was *my* upvote! See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498952/vba-how-to-create-a-class-module-which-builds-objects-and-assigns-them-to-an-a/46499402#comment80022130_46499402).

Comment: Yes, I've run into that issue with UDT's, and I can't recall the last time I used one.

Comment: hehe.. I use them all the time, but only as `Private Type`, to hold internal class state (well you can see my deleted answer anyway) - passing them around is such a PITA I'd rather just create a dumb class instead =)

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to do this.  When you run the macro, the debug window will show both the initial and the changed values of the stored object.

If you do not use the `Key`, you need to reference the collection item by its index number.

## Class Module

```
Option Explicit
'RENAME cNodes

Private pNode1 As Variant
Private pNode2 As Variant

Public Property Get Node1() As Variant
    Node1 = pNode1
End Property
Public Property Let Node1(Value As Variant)
    pNode1 = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Node2() As Variant
    Node2 = pNode2
End Property
Public Property Let Node2(Value As Variant)
    pNode2 = Value
End Property
```

## Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Sub ChangeCollectionItem()
    Dim COL As Collection, cN As cNodes
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim a, b

Set COL = New Collection
    a = 1
    b = 2
    Set cN = New cNodes
    With cN
        .Node1 = a
        .Node2 = b
        sKey = a & "|" & b

        COL.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=cN

        Debug.Print COL(sKey).Node1, COL(sKey).Node2 '-->  1      2

        With COL(sKey)
            .Node1 = .Node1 * 10
            .Node2 = .Node2 * 5
        End With

        Debug.Print COL(sKey).Node1, COL(sKey).Node2 '-->  10      10
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not changing the value of the item, but values of the instance properties, it is not the same thing. You are trying to prove that you can modify the value of an item in a collection, this does not prove it.

Comment: Change item 1 to another instance and I would change my statement

Comment: My question is properly answered as asked. Why not change your statement in your other post "*You cannot store a user-defined object in a collection*".  That is still there at the beginning of your answer, and that statement is wrong.

Comment: @Ibo Ron is correct. Your answer on the linked question is incorrect, OP doesn't involve UDT's at all, and the term "user-defined type" in VBA stands for types created using the `Type` keyword, **not class modules**. You cannot change the **reference** of an object stored in a collection at a given index, *that* is correct. Wording matters.

Comment: I used a better wording, however, you are still trying to prove that you can change the items in a collection without remove and add routines, good luck!

Comment: @Ibo  - your reading of the question seems to be off?  The OP asks about "alter[ing] the properties of the class" while it's stored in a collection: Ron's answers shows that to be possible (assuming the OP really means an *instance* of a class, and not the class itself, which I think is a reasonable assumption)

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah, this was related to another question to which you submitted an answer. I did not read the title carefully, but this answer is 100% correct for Ron's own question, but he insisted he can change the value of an item without removing and adding a collection item.

Comment: @Ibo - "he insisted he can change the value of an item without removing and adding a collection item". Do you mean Ron insisted?  I don't see that, and you seem to be the one insisting here...  When Ron writes "the debug window will show both the initial and the changed values of the stored object" it's pretty clear he's talking about the values of the object's *properties*.

Comment: @TimWilliams Please go back to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498952/vba-how-to-create-a-class-module-which-builds-objects-and-assigns-them-to-an-a) and see how he comes back to me. Please note that he said: `You are incorrect regarding how to change the value of an item in a collection.` and then I clearly said: `How about you just show us how you change it without removing and adding it?` and I meant a collection item and not a class instance properties stored as an item. It is clear for most of VBA developers that one cannot change the value of an item of a collection

Comment: @TimWilliams again, ron's quote was `You are incorrect regarding how to change the value of an item in a collection.` note that he said VALUE OF AN ITEM IN A COLLECTION. value of the item in his post is not an item value, but a class instance properties. The item value happens to be the user-defined class instance/object, so he did not change it, he cannot change it because VBA does not allow any direct change of the item.

Comment: @I'm not interested in getting into any dispute, and I guess I should have refrained from making any comment in the first place. My interpretation and yours are different, so I'm happy to leave leave it at that.

Comment: @Ibo I think we are into semantics.  To me, if the value of an Item's property is "x", and I change it to "y", I have changed the value of the Item.  And this whole discussion was in the context of UDO's being stored in Collections.  But I am happy to see that you have removed your statement about being unable to store a UDO in a collection.